# Background worker and garbage collection?

Tags: c#

Can I define a background worker in a method ?

```
private void DownLoadFile(string fileLocation){
  BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

  worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((obj, args) => { 
      // Will be executed by back ground thread asynchronously.
      args.Result = Download(fileLocation);   
  });

  worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((obj, args) => { 
      // will be executed in the main thread.
      Result r = args.Result as Result;
      ReportResult(r);
   });

   worker.RunWorkerAsync(fileLocation);
}
```

**Question**: If Download() function takes a long time to download the file, can GC kick in and collect worker object before the RunWorkerCompleted() is executed ?

Comment: I'd recommend using a delegate (Action(Of String) would do) and then calling BeginInvoke. I don't see any need for the BackgroundWorker in this code. You can still attach an event for when the method is done.

Comment: A better way to do this would be to add it to the thread pool queue using `QueueUserWorkItem` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx

Comment: @J... The threadpool is nice, but it does make handling the callback *on the right SynchronizationContext* more difficult.  The TPL handles that nicely, though.

Comment: @ReedCopsey True enough, but TPL is .NET 4.0+ only (I think) so thread pool is a viable alternative (OP doesn't state framework version).

Comment: @J... (Or 3.5 with Rx Framework) - but yes, you'd have to manage the SychronizationContext posting yourself with QUWI

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given that you're not actually using much of the functionality of BackgroundWorker, I would recommend using the TPL for this instead:

```
private void DownLoadFile(string fileLocation)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => Download(fileLocation))
        .ContinueWith(t => ReportResult(t.Result), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

---

That being said, the `worker` object will not be garbage collected once it's running, as the ThreadPool thread itself will keep worker as a "used object".  The garbage collector will not be able to collect it until after the completion event handler executes, at which point in time there would be no user code which could reach the instance of `BackgroundWorker`.

In addition, it will likely keep the instance of this class from being garbage collected, as the instance methods (`ReportResults`) used by the closure keep the instance of "this" accessible and not eligible for GC.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the OP's question. Still good advice though.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Added a direct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to let a variable like that go out of scope, though?  The programmer coming after him will expect to see an in-scope variable being referenced, not some zombie variable that's out there in the ether somewhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No - which is why I suggested switching models here.  I would never use BW in this way.  It'll work, but it's really odd code to use it like that. (That being said, it's not all that different than using ThreadPool.QUWI directly...)

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Thanks, you not only confirmed my theory of closure but also suggested a better way - appreciate it. + 1